# Remove Pop!_OS login password

Tags: login, password

I know this has been asked before, but I couldnt find a solution that fits my needs.

I am the only user on my PC (running Pop!_OS 20.10). Nobody has access to my computer because I live alone. This is why I want to remove my login password.

How can I achieve the following things:

1. No password required to log in
2. No "Unlock Login Keyring" popup after login without password
3. A password for sudo is still required
4. When the computer goes to sleep because I haven't used it for a while and then wake it up again I don't want to have to enter a password

So far I have tried to enable "Automatic Login" in Settings>Users>Authentication & Login. But this only solves problem 1 and 3. After booting up, I am always asked for a password for "Unlock Login Keyring". And after waking up my unused computer, I also need a password.

I also have tried removing the Password from my user. But after that I couldnt execute sudo commands anymore because I had no password.

Answer (score 0):

No authentication after lock screen on pop os :
Settings >  Privacy > Screen
Then uncheck 'Automatic screen lock' && 'Lock screen on suspend'